# How to convert Android color class integer type object into human understandable string

Tags: android

I want to create a random color from rgb(r,g,b) and want to display its name in a `TextView`.

This code of mine isn't working:

```
t.setText("the color is  "+Integer.toHexString(c.rgb(r, g, b)));
```

Comment: How does your code not work? What do you expect to see, what do you actually see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.iam.uni-bonn.de/~alt/latex/rgb.txt is a list of colour names (it is part of the MIT-licensed X11R6, so you can include it in your own code without overly problematic legal limitations).  You could load the items from it into an ArrayList, then scan through finding the distance between your colour and each item of the list, and use the name of the closest one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print `the color is GREEN`, for example, then I think you'll have to write your own algorithm and setup some thresholds defining when you think a color turns from one name to another (e.g. from GREEN to BLUE). You would then pass the color code to that algorithm and get back the name of that color.

Writing such an algorithm doesn't even have to be that complicated. You could compare the base color components of your custom color and find the dominant component. Depending how much it dominates you can find your thresholds and hence your color names.